# How to switch back to English keyboard input in urxvt?

Tags: urxvt

I just started using urxvt with emacs and there is some keyboard shortcut I'm accidentally typing that is changing the keyboard input to cyrillic or greek (not sure which). What keyboard shortcut am I probably accidentally typing? How do I switch back to U.S. English? How do I disable this keyboard shortcut?

I am only using the font-size extension, and these are my .Xresources lines for urxvt:

```
urxvt.iso14755: false
urxvt.font: xft:Source Code Pro:style=Regular:size=12
urxvt.scrollBar: false
urxvt.saveLines: 1048576
urxvt.termName: screen-256color
urxvt.perl-ext-common: font-size
urxvt.keysym.C-plus: font-size:increase
urxvt.keysym.C-underscore: font-size:decrease
```

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally typing ALT+SHIFT. Typing it again cycled back to English.